# Add labels to nodes in Hobbelt's "Group/Bundle Nodes" D3 force layout example?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, force-layout

I adapted Ger Hobbelt's excellent example of group/bundle nodes
https://gist.github.com/GerHobbelt/3071239

as a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/tco2fkad/

The display demonstrates both collapsible nodes and regions (hulls).

The one tweak that eludes me is how to add labels to expanded nodes. I have successfully added labels to nodes in my other force network diagrams using code similar to:

```
nodes.append("text")
     .attr("class", "nodetext")
     .attr("dx", 12)
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .text(function(d) {
         // d.name is a label for the node, present in the JSON source
         return d.name;
     });
```

Is anyone familiar enough with Ger's example to guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On enter, instead of appending `circle` append a `g` with a `circle` and a `text`.  Then re-factor a bit to fix the movement of the `g` instead of the `circle`.  Finally, append write out the `.text()` only if the node has a name (meaning it's a leaf):

```
node = nodeg.selectAll("g.node").data(net.nodes, nodeid);
node.exit().remove();
var onEnter = node.enter();   
var g = onEnter
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.size?"":" leaf"); })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
  });   
g.append("circle")
  // if (d.size) -- d.size > 0 when d is a group node.      
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size ? d.size + dr : dr+1; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    expand[d.group] = !expand[d.group];
    init();
  });  
g.append("text")
  .attr("fill","black")
  .text(function(d,i){
    if (d['name']){          
      return d['name'];
    }
});
```

And refactored tick to use `g` instead of circle:

```
 node.attr("transform", function(d) { 
   return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
 });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tco2fkad/4/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Mark. I need to go through the code more to understand it, then see if I can apply it to the bundled nodes as well.

Comment: I adapted your code to my own data and now have a strange problem. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/7yu2g1b2/   . Expand the orange node. Then expand the blue. Node 18 detaches from within the orange (no "link" ) until you collapse the blue hull again.  Any idea what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Created a new question to address this curious issue, here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987690/d3-js-force-layout-group-bundle-nodes-links-breaking