# d3.js force layout: group/bundle nodes - links breaking

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I adapted Ger Hobbelt's original work with the assistance of @Mark to add labels to the expanded nodes in a previous Stackoverflow post:

[Add labels to nodes in Hobbelt's "Group/Bundle Nodes" D3 force layout example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836035/add-labels-to-nodes-in-hobbelts-group-bundle-nodes-example)

When I added my own data to the reworked example I observe the most peculiar problem. See the new fiddle, below. Expand the orange node. Then expand the blue. Node 18 detaches from within the orange hull (the link for node 18 is gone! ) and there appears to be an invisible node in an extra link between nodes 25 and 13. If you collapse the blue hull again then the links appear normally.  There must be an issue with how the links are calculated but I can't see it. Any idea what is causing this behaviour?

https://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/7yu2g1b2

```
  link.enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.size || 1; });
```

Could it be related to the order of defining the links and the nodes? See the code in the fiddle that follows link.enter() where var g and g.append are defined.

Comment: It's a pain to debug using jsfiddle, better to create a html file and then you can use the browser tools to see what's going on. You will see that there is a problem with the calculation of some of the attributes: they will have value NaN and that is causing the links to fail. Most probably you are changing the structure of the link and node data without re-initialising the layout with `force.start()`, but my point is that your work-flow doesn't seem to include using the browser tools to see for yourself what's going on.